# Is it possible to add custom command shortcuts in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, command, shortcut

I'm curious about the vscode function,

is it possible to add custom command shortcut by any idea including extensions and so on?

For example, I want to put these codes with simple keyboard action like 'Ctrl+Shift+1'.

```
if (canvas.getContext){
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //console.log("canvas supported!");

}
else {
  //console.log("canvas unsupported.");
}
```

and when I put 'Ctrl+Shift+1', the code that I saved past appears and able to use it.

If you know the answer, please spare your time.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you want 10 clipboards? Or do you want snippets. You can insert a snippet with a key binding

Comment: @rioV8 wow yes! that's what I was looking for! thanks a lot:D